# Websocket wss configurations in nginx, django, daphne

Tags: django, nginx, daphne

I have a Django server which uses websockets (Django channels). I have the following configurations of daphne and nginx.

What the right way to configure ngnix for wss websockets?

Here's what I have:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/trading-backend**

```
server {
    server_name trading-backend-test.myserver.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/vagram/trading-backend/static_root/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/vagram/trading-backend/media_root/;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/vagram/run/daphne.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/vagram/trading-backend.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/trading-backend-test.myserver.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/trading-backend-test.myserver.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = trading-backend-test.myserver.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name trading-backend-test.myserver.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

**/etc/systemd/system/daphne.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/daphne.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**/etc/systemd/system/daphne.service**

```
Description=WebSocket Daphne Service
Requires=daphne.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=vagram
WorkingDirectory=/home/vagram/trading-backend/src
ExecStart=/home/vagram/trading-backend/env/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 project.asgi:application
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: proxy_pass http://unix:/home/vagram/run/daphne.sock; 
How about remove http like "unix:/home/vagram/run/daphne.sock; "